# Custom Collection filtered with sortOrder() not showing higher values first(DESC)

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, sql, sorting

I have a custom collection that gets updated/increases the attribute called "views" by 1 per view/access (observer records each view).

I later filter this collection to output data for viewing (see below);

```
$TopViews->setOrder('views', 'DESC');
```

The sort is outputting 2 ~ 9 above 10 etc (like the default product sort values) as per example below (foreach);

```
5 views
3 views
2 views
22 views
...
10 views
```

but really the higher the number should be output first. Maybe its the way i have created my table column in the sql setup file as I see that ID values are sorted correctly when using this.

SQL Setup;

```
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`views` varchar(255) default NULL,
```

How would I filter the collection correctly to output higher values first (DESC)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are strings, so they are sorted alphanumerical. You could work around this by implicitly casting the strings to numbers:

```
setOrder(new Zend_Db_Expr('views + 0'), 'DESC')
```

(see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql)

But the real question is, why do you store "X views" as varchar and not "X" as integer?

Comment: Thanks mate, setOrder(new Zend_Db_Expr('views + 0'), 'DESC') work as per your suggestion. "X" as integer? - didnt think that far ahead..

Comment: I'd recommend you to change that, then you can also add a MySQL index to the column to improve sorting performance